# How do I hide a form field?

Tags: php, html

How do I hide a particular form field when a field is selected from a drop down in HTML?

Comment: do you want to hide it at the client side (javascript) or on server side? please be more specific!

Comment: At client side i am using html and php

Comment: @user1162524 `PHP` is **server**-side!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php, as content has already been served to browser. So, a handy solution is to use javascript

```
<select name="foobar" onchange="checkAndHide(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="right1">right1</option>
<option value="wrong">wrong</option>
<option value="right2">right2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="shouldHide" name="test">

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAndHide(value){

    if(value == 'wrong')
        document.getElementById('shouldHide').style.display = 'none';

    else
        document.getElementById('shouldHide').style.display = 'block';

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you must use something that can communicate with the header which requires JavaScript or jquery, etc.

I don't have an example as I'm at work but I used jquery to load another page after a category is selected. This page generates the rest of the select fields (my sub categories) using a query and while statement ,inside the option tag once a category has been picked. There are many examples on google, just google jquery dynamic dropdown box